# How can I show list of android native views in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Let's say I have a widget coded in dart which shows android native view by using PlatformViewLink.

I want to make a list of that widget dynamically(want to add/remove by user's actions).

But I don't know how to add the multiple widgets dynamically to android activity because the widget uses Platform Link and it seems like they can register only one view by calling

```
flutterEngine
  .platformViewsController
  .registry
  .registerViewFactory("myViewTypeId", MyViewFactory())
```

Creating the widget multiple times by dart but it didn't work.

[image]